# Spring Boot @ControllerAdvice @ExceptionHandler content type via an annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I know e.g. status can be set via an annotation:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public String handleMyException(MyException myException) {
    return myException.getMessage();
}
```

I know I can make a `ResponseEntity` with the appropriate content type like this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleMyException(MyException myException) {
    return ResponseEntity
        .badRequest()
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
        .body(myException.getMessage());
}
```

Is it possible to set the content type via annotation only, i.e. something like this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
@ContentType(MediaType.TEX_PLAIN_VALUE)
public String handleMyException(MyException myException) {
    return myException.getMessage();
}
```

I couldn't find an annotation that would do that.

Answer (score 1):

According to spring documentation (same for boot as well), you can set only @ResponseStatus annotation with ExceptionHandler.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html